# How to convert to decimal type in Protobuf.js

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers, protobuf-csharp-port

I want to exchange website data with a window application in `protobuf.net` and `protobuf.js`.
I have a problem with `protobuf.js` that haven't decimal type.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The Parser, which is only part of the full build of protobuf.js, supports the legacy groups, float and double as stated [here](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/wiki/Parser).